# Datatable generate different column with original columns

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, datatable, datatables-1.10

I am using datatable v1.10.13 and asp.net web app.

I am trying to load data with ajax, but I have a problem in one of my forms,
when I generate data that not match in columns and I get an error as below:

> DataTables warning: table id=notifications1sa - Requested unknown parameter '2' for row 0, column 2. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

My javascript is as below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sample').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/sample/loadtable",
                "method": "POST"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "title", "title": "Header Title" },
                { "data": "message", "title": "Text Header" }
            ],
            "ordering": true,
            "paging": true,
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "pageLength": 10,
            "language": {
                "url": "/js/plugins/tables/datatables/German.json"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And my HTML is like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-flat">
<table id="sample" class="table" style="width: 100%">
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are calling the datatable in document.ready which will call after dom creation. Then you are loading your data.thats why it is not working

Call datatable in success of ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [**`defaultContent`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent). You can specify a default value to use if the data property not exists :

```
...
columns: [
  { data: "title", 
    title: "Header Title" 
    defaultContent: '(not set)'
  },
  { data: "message", 
    title: "Text Header" 
    defaultContent: '(not set)'
  }
],
...
```